# Remove From Family Share

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

A few months ago a friend and I family shared eachother, and have since not talked to eachother.  We are no longer friends and I have removed him from my family share, but I want him to remove me from his.

Is there anyway to do this without having the other person involved?

[image: Games List]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

**Delete a shared library**

So that you need the other way around there is a good and a bad message.

The bad one is

> Get them to remove you, its a one way set up.
> Removing them from you share doesn't remove you from thier shares.

The good one however, there is a [**workaround available**](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/familysharing/discussions/0/540736965953254153/#c540741859137412566) which I've not tested but as you just have to comment out a few lines you can't kill anything.

---

### Managing and Revoking Access

> Unlike the process of authorisation, managing and revoking access to your Steam library can be handled entirely within your own Steam client. To do this, open Steam > Preferences (Steam > Settings on Windows), select the Family section again and click Manage Other Computers.
>
> To revoke authorisation for a specific device, and free up one of your ten slots, click the Revoke link next to the name of that device. For reference, the Steam community name of the person who uses that device to access your library will be shown under By Steam User.
>
> Note, however, that if the person is authorised on any additional devices, they will still be able to access your library on those particular devices.

[image: steam revoke]

> To revoke access to a person (and free up one of your five slots), click the Revoke link next to the name of that user. This listing will show the user's current Steam community name, so you should reference the time they were added if unclear.

[Source](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-steam-family-sharing--cms-21018)

Comment: This doesn't help me, I need it the other way around.  Someone who family shared to me, is who I want to remove.

Comment: Is your friends library the only one you got shared?

Comment: Yes, but I had at someone at some point but I asked them to remove me because I had all the games they had.

Comment: Did you try to disable the whole family sharing?

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you can solve this problem by simply reinstalling steam.

Answer (score 0):

No, The other person has to disable their family share.

You could go to your family share settings and disable that but i'm not sure that way will work.

Comment: No it didn't, on my end, I've completely removed him.  His computer and accounts are no longer authorized, but that doesn't affect his end.

Comment: Then he will have to disable family share on his end then sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can control it with a community tool called [sfs-select](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/familysharing/discussions/1/3068621701744549116/).

If you want to avoid the above program, you can also edit the "AuthorizedDevice" section of the "Steam\config\config.vdf" file manually, which will require you to identify the account by putting its number in a link such as https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=123456789.